# Object issue in LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am getting an Object Reference issue from the following left outer join LINQ Query :

```
result.Data = from c in resourceActions.Actions
                      join o in roleResourceActions.Actions on c.ActionID equals o.ActionID into g
                      from a in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     ActionID=c.ActionID,
                     ActionName=c.ActionName
                     ,IsSelected = a.ActionName==null?false:true
                 };
```

When I traced the above LINQ Query, it seems that the object "a" itself is null. But based on this object only I can get the value for "IsSelected"

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `a` to be null in some queries, you can test for it before read `ActionName`:

```
result.Data = from c in resourceActions.Actions
                  join o in roleResourceActions.Actions on c.ActionID equals o.ActionID into g
              from a in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  ActionID=c.ActionID,
                  ActionName=c.ActionName,
                  IsSelected = a != null && a.ActionName != null
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result.Data = from c in resourceActions.Actions
                      join o in roleResourceActions.Actions on c.ActionID equals o.ActionID into g
                      from a in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     ActionID=c.ActionID,
                     ActionName=c.ActionName
                     ,IsSelected = a != null && a.ActionName==null ? false : true
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx), which will return the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) value for the type of the query you call it on.

Since the type of your query is a reference type, [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx) returns `null`.

So the solution depends on wheter you want your query to return an element if your `join` yields elements or not.

If not, just remove it:

```
result.Data = from c in resourceActions.Actions
              join o in roleResourceActions.Actions on c.ActionID equals o.ActionID into g
              from a in g
              select new
              {
                 ActionID=c.ActionID,
                 ActionName=c.ActionName,
                 IsSelected = a.ActionName==null?false:true
              };
```